# Rails 3 ActiveRecord: Find model by finding it's association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

```
class OrderItem belongs_to Item and belongs_to Order

class Item has_many OrderItems and belongs_to ItemType

class ItemType has_many Items

class Order has_many OrderItems
```

I would like to, within Order, find all OrderItems whose Items are of type ItemType

```
def get_by_item_type(id)
  order_items.where(:item => {:item_type_id => 3})
```

Obviously I can do this by finding all OrderItems, looping, testing, and building my own collection. No problem there, but I wonder if there is another way?

Thanks
/j

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be done with:

```
def get_by_item_type(id)
  order_items.joins(:item).where(:item_type_id => id)
end
```

If you get an error about a non existing/ambiguous column, have a look at

```
order_items.joins(:items).to_sql
```

in order to find the correct column names.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out as soon as possible as it looks about right...Thanks

Comment: Finally got to implement this part of the system and worked like a charm.